# Modal Logic equipped with "$\overline{\Diamond}$"

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, modal-logic

I am looking for some bibliography or works dealing with a modal operator $\overline{\Diamond}$ whose interpretation over a Kripke model would be $x\models\overline{\Diamond}\varphi$ iff there exists $y$ **not** accessible from $x$ such that it satifies $\varphi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to handle these "derived relations" is by adding additional relations to our frame, and working in a [multimodal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_logic).

We can encode your desired behavior by adding an additional relation $\overline{R}$ to our kripke frame, and specifying that $(a,b) \in \overline{R} \iff (a,b) \not \in R$. Then we interpret $\overline{\lozenge} \varphi$ as a usual "diamond operator", where we use $\overline{R}$ instead of $R$.

Practically all of modal logic goes through in these multimodal settings. If you want a book written in this level of generality, you might consider Blackburn, de Rijke, and Venema's [*Modal Logic*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modal-logic/F7CDB0A265026BF05EAD1091A47FCF5B).

---

I hope this helps ^_^